# Issues with mysql in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a small problem with connecting c# with a mysql database. When im trying to insert a value from a textbox i get the error below. I was wondering if someone could help me/ explain to me what im doeing wrong.

This is the error that i'm getting:
Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'

This is my code for connecting to the database:

```
namespace Planner
{
    internal class DBConnect
    {
        private MySqlConnection _connection = new MySqlConnection();
        private string _server;
        private string _database;
        private string _uid;
        private string _password;
        //private string _port;
        //private bool succes = false;


        //Constructor
        public DBConnect()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        //Initialize values
        public void Initialize()
        {
            string connectionString2 = "Server=localhost;Port=3307;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=usbw";

            //+ "Port:" + _port + ";"
            _server = "localhost:3307";
            //_port = "3307";
            _database = "test";
            _uid = "root";
            _password = "usbw";

            string connectionString = "Server=" + _server + ";"  + "Database=" +
                               _database + ";" + "Uid=" + _uid + ";" + "Pwd=" + _password + ";";

            _connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString2);
        }

        public bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                _connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server");
                        break;
                    case 1042:
                        MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts");
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password");
                        break;
                }
                return false;

            }


        }

        private List<string>[] Select()
        {
            string selectquery = "SELECT * FROM tabelname";

            List<string>[] selectlist = new List<string>[3];
            selectlist[0] = new List<string>();
            selectlist[1] = new List<string>();
            selectlist[2] = new List<string>();


            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectquery, _connection);

            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                selectlist[0].Add(dataReader["waarde"] + "");
                selectlist[1].Add(dataReader["waarde"] + "");
                selectlist[2].Add(dataReader["waarde"] + "");
            }

            dataReader.Close();

            return selectlist;
        }

        public void Insert(string textvalue)
        {
            string insertquery = "INSERT INTO testconnectie(text) VALUES ("+textvalue+")";


                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertquery, _connection);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();




        }

        private void Update()
        {
            string updatequery = "UPDATE tabelnaam SET waarde='', waarde'' WHERE waarde=''";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = updatequery;
            cmd.Connection = _connection;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        private void Delete()
        {
            string deletequery = "DELETE FROM tabelnaam WHERE waarde=''";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(deletequery, _connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        public bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                _connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;

            }

        }


        public void Backup()
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime Time = DateTime.Now;
                int year = Time.Year;
                int month = Time.Month;
                int day = Time.Day;
                int hour = Time.Hour;
                int minute = Time.Minute;
                int second = Time.Second;
                int millisecond = Time.Millisecond;

                //Save file to C:\ with the current date as a filename
                string path;
                path = "C:\\ChatBackup" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day +
            "-" + hour + "-" + minute + "-" + second + "-" + millisecond + ".sql";
                StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path);


                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "Database Backup";
                psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}",
            _uid, _password, _server, _database);
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;

                Process process = Process.Start(psi);

                string output;
                output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                file.WriteLine(output);
                process.WaitForExit();
                file.Close();
                process.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error , unable to backup! " + ex);
            }
        }



    }

}
```

Mainform

```
namespace Planner
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private DBConnect mysql = new DBConnect();


        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mysql.Initialize();
            mysql.OpenConnection();

        }

        private void _sendMessageButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            string textvalue = _messageTextBox.Text;
            mysql.Insert(textvalue);

        }


        }
}
```

Can someone explain to my what im doeing wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll put a screenshot of the table in my question

Comment: As said in an answer, use quotes. Better though, is to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you miss single quote, use like this

```
string insertquery = "INSERT INTO testconnectie(text) VALUES ('"+textvalue+"')";
```

Answer (score 1):

use parameters: it is safe and you can avoid most of the exceptions like you currently get

```
string insertquery = "INSERT INTO YourTableName ([yourColumnName]) VALUES (@ParameterName)";
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertquery, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParameterName", textvalue); 
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```